# SQL: How can i build a string from column values of one row?

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2, case-statement

I have rows like this...

```
|  NAME  |   RED  |  BLUE  |  GREEN  |
  LeAnn       1        0         1
  Jim         0        0         0
  Timothy     1        1         1
```

I want to write a select statement that would return the following rows...

```
| Name    | Note |
  LeAnn     RED, Green
  Jim       
  Timothy   RED, BLUE, GREEN
```

How can I do this? I tried using case statement but would only get one value in Note instead of multiple values.  Thanks!

**My Attempt:**

```
SELECT Name, 
       CASE
         WHEN Red = 1 THEN 'Red' + ', '
         WHEN Blue = 1 THEN 'Blue' + ', '
         WHEN Green = 1 THEN 'Green' + ', '
       END as Note
  FROM MyTable
```

Comment: Could you show us your attempt? Since you did get one value, I'm sure you were pretty close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the cases are not mutually exclusive, you need three separate cases:

```
SELECT ('' + 
    CASE WHEN Red = 1 THEN 'Red, ' ELSE '' END
+   CASE WHEN Blue = 1 THEN 'Blue, ' ELSE '' END
+   CASE WHEN Green = 1 THEN 'Green, ' ELSE '' END
)
AS Note
FROM MyTable
```

Comment: For anyone here struggling with this, I got this to work adding a `+` to the end of each CASE statement line (except for the last).

Comment: @Danny Thank you for the comment.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me over eight years later!

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Name, CASE WHEN RED = 1 THEN "RED " ELSE "" END + CASE WHEN BLUE = 1 THEN "BLUE " ELSE "" END + CASE WHEN GREEN = 1 THEN "GREEN" ELSE "" END
FROM tableName
```

There needs to be 3 separate cases, or it will only do one of them.

You would need to update the above to handle the commas properly as well, but im too lazy to put that in

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Name, 
   CONCAT(
      IF(Red = 1, 'Red', ''),
      IF(Red = 1 AND Blue = 1, ', ', ''),
      IF(Blue = 1, 'Blue', ''),
      IF(Red = 1 AND Green = 1 AND `Blue` = 0, ', ', ''),
      IF(Blue = 1 AND Green = 1, ', ', ''),
      IF(Green = 1, 'Green', '')
   ) AS Note
From Table
```

I think this should work! Let me know if it doesn't ;)

Comment: There is no such `IF` in T-SQL.

Comment: Will this work in Sql Server 2008? I'm getting a syntax error.

Comment: I guess not if you get a syntax error. CONCAT is not a sql server 2008 format and I guess the IF statement isn't as well. I think you might need to look at the post from @Tomalak below!

Comment: @pascalvgemert The `IF` statement is available in SQL Server. It does flow control. There is no `IF` function though, this is solved through `CASE WHEN`.

Answer (score 0):

What about this?

```
select name, left(Note, abs(len(Note) - 1)) from (
  select name, '' +
      CASE WHEN Red = 1 THEN 'Red, ' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Blue = 1 THEN 'Blue, ' ELSE '' END +
      CASE WHEN Green = 1 THEN 'Green, ' ELSE '' END
      as Note
  from t
) final
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  ''
  + ISNULL(NULLIF(Red, 0), 'Red, ')
  + ISNULL(NULLIF(Blue, 0), 'Blue, ')
  + ISNULL(NULLIF(Green, 0), 'Green, ')
  AS Note
FROM 
  TheTable
```

This will create a trailing comma that you'd have to trim. For example like this:

```
SELECT
  REPLACE(
    ''
    + ISNULL(NULLIF(Red, 0), 'Red, ')
    + ISNULL(NULLIF(Blue, 0), 'Blue, ')
    + ISNULL(NULLIF(Green, 0), 'Green, ') 
    + '$',
    ', $',
    ''
  ) AS Note
FROM 
  TheTable
```